# Populate a custom form with user data

Tags: forms

I want to create my own code for displaying and editing a logged in user's profile.

For that I want to create a custom page/form with the required form fields. I will use elementor pro forms for this. My current idea is to

1. intercept all page loads with a function handling a suitable action hook
2. check the page name whether it is the profile page
3. if so, populate the form fields on the page with the current user's data

Couple of questions:

1. Which action do I need to use to intercept when a(n arbitrary) page is loaded?
2. How do I access the form fields in the page?

Comment: how are you creating the forms?

Comment: I will use Elementor pro's forms widget.

Comment: the you need to contact their support, as any solution would need to be built specifically for that plugin, and only people who have that plugin are capable of trying to help you. There isn't a generic WordPress based solution for all form plugins

Comment: With the same reasoning you could send me to Wordpress support for every wordpress related question. Elementor is a wordpress plugin, and a very popular one. I think my question is legit. If you want to create custom user profiles, the only solution apart from using some standard form widget from any plugin provider is to use a dedicated plugin for that - and none I found is fully customizeable (at least unless you pay money for a premium version). So I want to create a simple solution for custom user profile pages with a fully customizable form widget (Elementor's).

Comment: Funny thing is that I found out how to build a custom user profile page with Elementor forms and some php. Since my question got closed for a dubious and not very educated reason, I will neither be able to share my insight, nor anybody else to profit from it. Thank you, who ever closed my question, you did a disservice to the Wordpress community.

Comment: I'm sure plenty of people will benefit from your solution in the place you share it, there are lots of places that are a good fit for this question, but unfortunately it does not fit this particular stack. Dev support for 3rd party products such as Elementor are off-topic here and not within the defined scope. If you disagree with the rules or scope, you should open a question on the [meta stack](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/). Comments are for clarifying a question, not for discussing the site and its rules.

Comment: Elementor is tied into Wordpress. It is extremely popular. It offers a form widget, meaning you can solve the problem without having to install another plugin. It is probably the simplest way to create fully customizable custom login, registration and user profile pages. It is a valid question to be asked here. I think your stance might be a tad narrow minded.

Comment: Btw, I suppose that in the end Elementor uses Wordpress objects for handling forms, so all I would have need is an explanation how to intercept the form page being loaded and accessing the form and its data. Elementor usage isn't really relevant. Isn't it funny how I didn't even mention Elementor in the beginning? It is *you* who made a big deal about what particular form widget implementation I was using, even though that doesn't play a role.

Comment: Elementor is a 3rd party plugin, even if 100% of users used it, which they don't, [**this stacks scope does not include 3rd party plugin dev support**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As I said, the comments are not a place you can argue this to get your question reopened, we have rules and a scope. The process is to post in the meta stack. I'm going to lock the comments now, if you want to try to change the scope of this stack of feel that your question does fit within the scope, you need to make your case in the meta stack, not here.